# How to enable log-back log stack trace og uncaught exceptions

Tags: java, exception, logging, logback

I'm very new to log back and want to try using it in my app. I tried to configure it as follows:

```
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>/file/log.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- daily rollover -->
        <fileNamePattern>/rotated/log.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>

        <!-- keep 30 days' worth of history capped at 3GB total size -->
        <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
        <totalSizeCap>16GB</totalSizeCap>
    </rollingPolicy>

    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<root level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</root>
```

When I write a simple application I have a problem that stacktraces of uncaught exceptions are not get logged:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    logger.info("Test")
    logger.error("TEST!")
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Exception")
}
```

And what I have in the log file is:

```
16:57:05.905 [main] INFO  com.App - Test
16:57:05.907 [main] ERROR com.App - TEST!
```

How to configure logging stacktraces of uncaught exceptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you can log uncaught exceptions outside your main() method at all. But what you CAN do is to use a "catch all" block in your main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    try
    {
        logger.info("Test");
        logger.error("TEST!");
        someMethodThatPropablyThrowsAnException();
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Exception");
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        logger.error(exception);
    }
}
```

This should log any exception thrown in your code that was not handled yet.